# In `_output.yml`, some parameters are getting ignored

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have defined certain pandoc options in `_output.yml`:

````
```
author: "abc"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
```
````

But, these get ignored, unless these are defined in the YAML header inside the R Markdown file.

Is this prohibited from including in the separate YAML file? Is so, could you please mention what other parameters should be defined inside the Markdown file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `_output.yml` file can only be used for setting the output formats, as explained within the [bookdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/output-formats.html). So you can specify anything which relates to the output format (HTML/PDF/Word) such as:

```
html_document:
  toc: TRUE
  theme: flatly
pdf_document:
  toc: FALSE
```

In your examples, the parameters you provide are about document content. So anything like `author`, `title`, `date`, `fontsize` can't be specified.

> This issue has also been addressed within the GitHub issues of [R Markdown](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/297) for further reading.

Comment: Thanks for the references. Unfortunate that the issue is closed without solving the underlying fundamental issue.

Comment: I don't think being able to specify document options in the `_output.yml` would be described as desired behaviour: the name of the file itself indicates it purpose. If you wish to provide arguments to YAML, you could explore feeding the pandoc arguments to the render function: `rmarkdown::render(input = "testBib.Rmd", output_format = rmarkdown::pdf_document(pandoc_args = rmarkdown::pandoc_variable_arg("author", "Name of Author")))`